# How to use a continuous variable as the color argument for a barplot with plotly?

Tags: r, leaflet, plotly

I've been working with a flexdashboard generated using Rmarkdown and had issues with a few plots not displaying. After much testing, I determined that the `color =` argument I was sending to the following plot was causing the problem:

```
p1 <- plot_ly(coursetable2,
    x = ~title,  
    color = ~open+enrolled, 
    y = ~percent, 
    type = 'bar', 
    name = 'Seats Taken', 
    text =~paste('Seats Taken: ', enrolled, '</br> Open Seats: ' , open))

p1
```

The `open` and `enrolled` variables are continuous numeric values.

The plot generated fine within RStudio, but failed to display in the html file generated once I knit the file.

Curiously enough, this also made a `leaflet` plot within the same file fail to display in the final html file.  The `leaflet` plot code is as follows:

```
mytext<-paste("City: ", maptable$name, "<br/>", "People: ", 
    maptable$val, "<br/>", sep="") %>%
    lapply(htmltools::HTML)

pal<-colorNumeric(
    palette = "viridis",
    domain = maptable$val)


leaflet(maptable) %>%
  addTiles()  %>%
  setView( lat=41.5, lng=-73 , zoom=8) %>%
  addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.BlackAndWhite") %>%
  addCircleMarkers(~long, ~lat,
  fillOpacity = 0.7, color=~pal(val), radius=~sqrt(val)+5, stroke=FALSE,
  label = mytext,
  labelOptions = labelOptions( style = list("font-weight" = "normal", 
  padding = "3px 8px"), textsize = "13px", direction = "auto")
  )
```

The warning I receive says:

> textfont.color doesn't (yet) support data arrays

When I take the color argument out of the above code for the `p1` plot, all of my graphics display.

If I define a palette, as in the code below, all plots generate fine.

```
pal2<-colorNumeric(
   palette="viridis",
   domain=coursetable2$enrolled+coursetable2$open
   )

p1<-plot_ly(coursetable2,
    x = ~title,  
    showlegend=FALSE,
    color = ~pal2(open+enrolled), 
    y = ~percent, 
    type = 'bar', 
    name = 'Seats Taken', 
    text =~paste('Seats Taken: ', enrolled, '</br> Open Seats: ' , open))

p1
```

This solves the color problem I was having, but I'm stumped as to why passing the color argument in the original code fails.  And why BOTH plots fail in this case.  Is my fix the ideal solution for passing a continuous variable to the color argument for a bar plot?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general solution to formatting plot.ly using unsupported data types, try casting the data from your unsupported type (data array) to a supported type (factor) using the base-r function **as.factor()**. In python you can do the equivalent using astype("category").

If you're using R, you could cast inside the plot.ly object as follows:

```
p1 <- plot_ly(coursetable2,
    x = ~title,  
    color = as.factor(~open+enrolled), 
    y = ~percent, 
    type = 'bar', 
    name = 'Seats Taken', 
    text =~paste('Seats Taken: ', enrolled, '</br> Open Seats: ' , open))

p1
```

You can also use this approach to solve similar errors with other plot.ly formatting constraints; a cursory check and I was able to reproduce both the warning message and solution above for the 'trace' attribute 'line.color'.

```
Warning: line.color doesn't (yet) support data arrays
```

Comment: Once the color variable becomes a factor the color scale is then discrete, with a distinct color per value instread of a color scale.