# For a plotly polar plot in R, why isn't the line taking the colors from the color argument, but the legend has a color scale?

Tags: r, plotly, polar-plot

I'm trying to create a polar plot where the line colour changes across a gradient based on the year of the observation (e.g. there are 90 years of date, by month, plotted with a line on a polar plot, and as the years progress, I also want the color of the line to progress along the gradient).

I'm getting a legend showing the color gradient range, but the line itself isn't matching at all.

I'm getting the following error message.

```
line.color doesn't (yet) support data arrays
```

Here is the code I'm running:

```
gsod_temp %>%
  filter(ctry == 'AU') %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  plot_ly(type = 'scatterpolar', 
          mode = 'lines') %>%
  add_trace(r = ~avg_temp, 
            theta = ~(360*(mo_num/12)),
            color = ~year
            )
```

Structure of the gsod_temp dataframe is:

```
tibble [168,912 × 10] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ ...1     : num [1:168912] 19 45 46 47 83 84 85 86 87 140 ...
 $ ctry     : chr [1:168912] "RU" "DE" "GB" "IE" ...
 $ year     : num [1:168912] 1931 1932 1932 1932 1933 ...
 $ mo       : chr [1:168912] "01" "01" "01" "01" ...
 $ avg_temp : num [1:168912] 28.6 37 45 47.4 41.9 ...
 $ Name     : chr [1:168912] "Russian Federation" "Germany" "United Kingdom" "Ireland" ...
 $ year_mo  : num [1:168912] 193101 193201 193201 193201 193301 ...
 $ mo_num   : num [1:168912] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ date     : Date[1:168912], format: "1931-01-01" "1932-01-01" ...
 $ mo_factor: Ord.factor w/ 12 levels "01"<"02"<"03"<..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

And some example data:

```
> head(gsod_temp)
# A tibble: 6 × 10
   ...1 ctry   year mo    avg_temp Name            year_mo mo_num date       mo_factor
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>             <dbl>  <dbl> <date>     <ord>    
1    19 RU     1931 01      28.6   Russian Federa…  193101      1 1931-01-01 01       
2    45 DE     1932 01      37.0   Germany          193201      1 1932-01-01 01       
3    46 GB     1932 01      45.0   United Kingdom   193201      1 1932-01-01 01       
4    47 IE     1932 01      47.4   Ireland          193201      1 1932-01-01 01       
5    83 IE     1933 01      41.9   Ireland          193301      1 1933-01-01 01       
6    84 KZ     1933 01       0.517 Kazakhstan       193301      1 1933-01-01 01
```

What am I doing wrong?

If I convert the year to a factor, I get one colour by year, but then it's a discrete set of colours, one for each year, instead of a non-discrete color scale.

Here's the output:

[image: A polar plot made with plotly in R, showing average monthly temperature, with a colour scale for year, but the line is solid orange]

Here's a test dataset that can be run against this code:

```
gsod_temp <- data.frame(
  ctry = "AU",
  year = c(2021,2022,2023,2021,2022,2023,2021,2022,2023,2021,2022,2023,2021,2022,2023,2021,2022,2023,2021,2022,2023,2021,2022,2023,2021,2022,2023,2021,2022,2023,2021,2022,2021,2022
  ),
  avg_temp = c(73.7015450651341,75.4104290076383,73.6868657848023,72.2521273258409,73.1598298903227,73.4616700246468,70.1546055016525,71.9082260213444,71.2348908276238,65.3337760102265,67.2879372517948,65.4183841482946,60.3262843120212,61.1217217232473,58.5109055884243,56.5089054849122,55.9951720218307,56.9544276966095,55.8852550612849,54.0446941350753,56.258190531307,57.8043905662884,57.1572954432571,58.4890723197841,61.1094747395333,60.643525057218,63.5242135946568,64.9447142925673,64.809677957349,65.1997852147852,67.7951035968358,66.7495405578443,72.3003820409705,70.6337899227766
  ),
  mo_num = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,10,10,10,11,11,12,12
  ),
  date = c("2021-01-01","2022-01-01","2023-01-01","2021-02-01","2022-02-01","2023-02-01","2021-03-01","2022-03-01","2023-03-01","2021-04-01","2022-04-01","2023-04-01","2021-05-01","2022-05-01","2023-05-01","2021-06-01","2022-06-01","2023-06-01","2021-07-01","2022-07-01","2023-07-01","2021-08-01","2022-08-01","2023-08-01","2021-09-01","2022-09-01","2023-09-01","2021-10-01","2022-10-01","2023-10-01","2021-11-01","2022-11-01","2021-12-01","2022-12-01"
  )
)

gsod_temp %<>% mutate(date = ymd(date))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also I tried having the color parameter set inside add_trace() as well but that was the same

Comment: could you pleae provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Reproduceable example would be nice. Taking a guess perhaps you could set the colors in the 'add_trace()' function.

Comment: thanks yes i will try to figure out how to make an example. I'm struggling to think how but I'll give it some thought. But yes I tried color in add_trace. Moves r, theta and color down to add_trace (I was creating 2 x traces by putting r and theta in plot_ly, and then nothing in add_trace) but still no longer on the color gradient. I'm wondering if it's because there are 12 observations (months) for each year, so 12 duplicates of year... But I will try to figure out something reproducible...

Comment: Is there a way to extract/output a dataframe as a data.frame() command? So I can export a subset and paste a data.frame statement that will allow you to load it in?

Comment: Updated the question to change r, theta, color to add_trace(), but much the same result. Just cleaner.

Comment: Use `dput` to export things in a copy-paste friendly way!

Comment: you mean `dput()`

Comment: How do you want to treat the segments of your line that start in one year and end in the next year? For instance you could change `color = ~year` to `color = factor(year)` but I don't think that will be quite satisfactory -- it will exclude segments connecting two years.

Comment: OK thank you all. I've added a dataframe definiton at the bottom that will create some suitable data for recreating the issue.

Comment: @JonSpring I'm wanting the segments of the line to gradually change colour through the gradient scale so that they start as one colour for the earliest year, and end at the other end of the gradient for the latest year, if that makes sense. I want the line to follow the color gradient in the legend as it progresses through the time series.

Comment: I haven't been able to crack this yet. One thing to note is that some ggplot geoms like `geom_line` do no allow aesthetics like color to change within a single series/group, so we have to use workarounds like `ggforce::geom_link` or a series of `geom_segment` where we parameterize the start and end of each segment. I presume the same design challenges exist with plotly's implementation, and we might need a similar workaround.

Comment: Thanks @JonSpring. I think you are correct, in the same way that a continuous variable is not supported with a bar plot in plotly per this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56049984/how-to-use-a-continuous-variable-as-the-color-argument-for-a-barplot-with-plotly

Comment: A counterpoint is that changing to mode='markers' does allow continuous colour variables for the dots.

Comment: I'm still not used to reading the plotly documentation. I see things like `autocolorscale` for the object *plotly.graph_objects.scatterpolar.marker.Line*, which specifies an array of numeric values should be set with `color`, but when added to either `plot_ly()` or `add_trace()` I still get the same error, plus new error `'scatterpolar' objects don't have these attributes: 'autocolorscale'`, so I guess I'm not understanding this correctly.

Comment: Ok I see my mistake. I was looking at the line of a marker, not an actual line object. *class* `plotly.graph_objects.scatterpolar.Line` specifies that the `color` property will only accept the following:

- A hex string (e.g. ‘#ff0000’)
- An rgb/rgba string (e.g. ‘rgb(255,0,0)’)
- An hsl/hsla string (e.g. ‘hsl(0,100%,50%)’)
- An hsv/hsva string (e.g. ‘hsv(0,100%,100%)’)
- A named CSS color

Comment: FYI - I tried ggplotly() as well to convert from ggplot for even a normal line chart (which supports continuous colour scale lines with scale_color_continuous() but plotly doesn't render the line at all (even though the data points are still present but invisible for hover).

Comment: I couldn't get gganimate to work. Not sure why (only rendering 1 frame)

Comment: Also, ggplot2 doesn't seem to have a continuous polar scatterplot, and when it converts a plot to polar it doesn't continue to render the maximum value back to the smallest value (i.e. continuous line) so gave up on that too. Plotly's scatterpolar is very good - it just can't support continuous colour scale for any line object it seems ("yet", so assume it will come).

Answer (score 0):

At this stage, the best conclusion I can reach is that plotly does not currently support continuous colour scales/colour scales derived from arrays for line objects (I assume it will come eventually given it says it is not supported "yet"). Short of some kind've of manually coded work-around (which I don't have) I think it is safe to say that this is currently not possible.